# Unable to create InnoDB tables. MySQL InnoDB support is required for CiviCRM but is either not available or not enabled in this MySQL database server

Tags: drupal, installation, upgrade, migration

I'm trying to install an old CiviCRM version on Drupal 6, the purpose is to migrate an old database data to the latest CiviCRM version, but I'm getting this error when I try to install CiviCRM in a clean Drupal install:

`Unable to create InnoDB tables. MySQL InnoDB support is required for CiviCRM but is either not available or not enabled in this MySQL database server.`

Everything else seems to be ok, I'm gettinig this error in a windows environment. First I tried with wamp, now I'm trying with Laragon. I tried also with vagrant and homestead which is a linux environment I think, same results.

I tried setting innoDB as the default engine and a lot stuff that is there on internet, but anything seems to work. Any idea?

[image: Error]

This is what "SHOW ENGINES" return:

[image: SHOW ENGINES]

Comment: What does 'show engines' produce?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-check-availability.html

Comment: @Aidan I've added a new picture, as you can see, InnoDB is enabled and is the default engine

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a unix system running AMPPS. I'm trying to install an old version of CiviCRM (3.3.6 on Drupal 6) for the purpose of upgrading to the latest version of CiviCRM and Drupal 7 to ensure PHP 7.1 compatibility. I also show InnoB as the default. @CésarEscudero, did you figure this out?

Comment: Check here. Sounds like we need a lower mysql version and need to check file permissions: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9448/innodb-is-default-but-cant-install

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `civicrm/install/index.php` and change the line with code `if ( $dbName != 'Drupal' )` and either exclude the entire if statement (comment it out) or change it to `if(true)`.

Comment: This doesn't work and needs to be edited for clarity and more detail.

Comment: are you installing a stand alone civic crm or with in drupal/jumula framework?

Comment: It is part of Drupal and I was able to get it to work after I figured out what you mean. I commented out the entire if argument.

Comment: sweet you can kindly flag the answer as useful with a few more details you find needful